# Typescript custom mapped type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to come up with a mapped `type` to transform object's properties from type `Vector` to `Array`.

I have this as of now

```
type ToArray<T> = { 
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Vector<any> ? Array<any> : T[P] 
}
```

How can I correctly map the `any` type? I'd like to retain the original generic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the inference behavior of conditional types to get the original parameter to `Vector`:

```
type ToArray<T> = { 
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Vector<infer U> ? Array<U> : T[P] 
}
```

For more details on `infer U` see the chapter 'Type inference in conditional types' [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: Woooh, that's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: If I compose `ToArray<Pick<MyType, 'one' | 'two' | 'three'>>`, and I miss one of the fields, the compiler does not warn me. Is that normal?

Comment: @LppEdd what do you mean miss one of the fields ? You don't pick all of them ? or you miss spell one of them ?

Comment: I mean that I don't use all of them. `<type>{ one: ..., two: ... }`

Comment: @LppEdd then yes, `Pick` by it's nature means you want to pick some arbitrary fields, the compiler can't know which. You can filter the fields of a specific type if that is what you want .. will post an answer with that shortly.

Comment: But if I specify the field `three` and then I don't insert it, shouldn't it know that?

Comment: @LppEdd if `MyType` does not have propert `three` it shodl give an error

Comment: Actually I mean the opposite, MyType has property `three`, but I don't include it in my casted object `{ one: ..., two: ... }`

Comment: @LppEdd `Pick` lets you pick any properties you want it will not warn you if you miss one, it has no reason to. But if you want all properties why use `Pick` at all ?

Comment: I thought Pick forced you to include the selected properties (no no, I need a  subset)