# Typescript mapped type composition

Tags: typescript

Following this question [Typescript custom mapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636570/typescript-custom-mapped-type) (thanks Titian Cernicova-Dragomir!)
I have this mapped type:

```
export type ToArray<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Vector<infer U> ? Array<U> : T[P]
}
```

Now, I want to join it with Pick.

```
<Pick<ToArray<Tag>, 'id' | 'name' | 'children' | 'hierarchyName'>>{
    id: t.id,
    name: t.name,
    children: t.children.toArray()
}
```

However the compiler doesn't force me to add `hierarchyName`, which does happen if I use:

```
<Pick<Tag, 'id' | 'name' | 'children' | 'hierarchyName'>>
```

How's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there are some definitions that look like those in your code (your actual code might be different, but this code is enough to demonstrate the problem):

```
interface Vector<E> {
    elements: E[];
    toArray(): E[];
}

interface Tag {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    children: Vector<Tag>;
    hierarchyName: string;
}

let t: Tag;
```

You are saying that you are getting expected error when one property is missing in this initializer:

```
const v1 = <Pick<Tag, 'id' | 'name' | 'children' | 'hierarchyName'>>{
    id: t.id,
    name: t.name,
    children: t.children.toArray()
};
```

Let's try to reduce it to a minimal example: remove `Pick`, and remove initializes for all properties:

```
const v2 = <Tag>{
};
```

**There's no error.**

Why? Because `<Tag>{}` is a [type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/25541) [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461479/what-is-the-type-assertion-operator-for-in-typescript), it's identical to `{} as Tag` - you are forcing the compiler to believe that the value actually has `Tag` type.

The compiler will seldom report errors for type assertions, after all, a type assertion is a way to tell the compiler that "I know better". In your case, it's reported only because `Tag` is a recursive type, it has `children` property which type is `Tag[]`, and it somehow makes the compiler to believe that a value can never be compatible with the type:

```
// error
const v2 = <Tag>{       
    children: t.children.toArray()
};
```

Transforming with `ToArray` makes type non-recursive: `children` in transformed type remain with `Tag` type, which is different from enclosing type, which makes the error go away.

The proper way to catch these errors is to use type annotation for variable declarations, not type assertions:

```
const v3: Tag = {}; // error
```

Comment: Indeed, using `const reducedTag: Pick<ToArray<Tag>, 'id' | 'name' | 'children' | 'hierarchyName'> = { ... }` reports the error. Thank you Artem! That's something I didn't know!